# PHP can't upload Video and Audio Files

Tags: php, upload

I am facing a problem, when I try to upload Audio or Video files to my website they do not upload.

I have added these lines to .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 1800
php_value max_input_time 1800
```

Worst thing is I ca not even upload audio or video files that are less than 1MB, but other files work like images and text.

I am using dopzone script for upload this is my code for upload:

```
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");
if(!empty($_FILES))
{   
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Riga');
        
    session_start();
    $token_unhashed = $_SESSION['share_token'];
    
    $sql_multiple = "SELECT share_token,share_views,share_expire,share_date FROM shares WHERE share_token='$token'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql_multiple);
    $exist = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($exist>=1)
    {
        $share_views = 0;
        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $expire_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+24 hours'));
    }
    else
    {
        $share_views = 0;
        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $expire_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+24 hours'));
        
        mkdir("web/shares/".$token_unhashed, 0777, true);
    }
    
    $UploadName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $UploadTmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    
    move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp, "web/shares/".$token_unhashed."/$UploadName");
    include("includes/generator.php");
        
    $sql = "INSERT INTO shares (share_token,share_uid,share_views,share_downloads,share_name,share_expire,share_date) 
    VALUES ('$token','$share_uid','$share_views','0','$UploadName','$expire_time','$datetime')";

    include("includes/logs.php");

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $address = ip_info($ip, "address");
    $browser = get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $os = getOS($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    $sql_logs = "INSERT INTO share_logs (ip,upload_name,browser,os,address,date) 
    VALUES ('$ip','$UploadName','$browser','$os','$address','$datetime')";

    $sql_update_total_uploads = "UPDATE stats SET total_uploads=total_uploads+1";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_update_total_uploads);
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql_logs);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

And this is html:

```
<div class='upload-panel c' style='margin-top: 40px;'>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" class="f-c upload dropzone">
        <div class="b s-22 dz-message needsclick">
            <i class='fa fa-cloud-upload-alt s-50' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            <div>Drop files here or click to upload.</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried to upload different files, some audio/video files it uploads but some not for example i  tried to upload 1MB audio file couldn't when i tried to upload different one 1.4MB it uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out
When you try to upload file which contains > ' < in name it will not upload so i added this line which changes file name, now everything works

```
    $UploadName_old = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $UploadTmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $UploadName = str_replace("'", "-", $UploadName_old);
```